# windows batch script to copy files and move to backup directory

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I have multiple folders that each contain a config folder.  In the config folder there is a .cfg file and a backup folder. I would like to copy the .cfg file to the backup folder with a date extension.
Here is my folder structure:

```
\Folder1\config

    folder1.cfg

    \backup

\Folder2\config

    folder2.cfg

    \backup

\Folder3\config

    folder3.cfg

    \backup
```

Each of the above folders has a config folder.  In each config folder there is a .cfg file and a backup folder.  How can I step through each Folder*\config directory and copy the folder*.cfg file to the backup folder and rename it to folder3.cfg.yyyymmdd?  I actually have about 40 folders that I would need to this for on a Windows server.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REM

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
for /f "delims=." %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "wmicdt=%%a"
SET "wmicdt=%wmicdt:~0,8%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%" ' ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a\config\%%a.cfg" (
  MD "%sourcedir%\%%a\config\backup" 2>NUL
  COPY /b "%sourcedir%\%%a\config\%%a.cfg" "%sourcedir%\%%a\config\backup\%%a.cfg.%wmicdt%" >nul
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit.

The `SET "wmicdt=%wmicdt:~0,8%"` line selects the first 8 characters of the date/time string in `wmicdt`, which is yyyymmdd. If you want the time as well, simply omit this line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.

```
@echo off

:loop
for /l %%g in (1,1,3) do (
        copy "Folders\Folder%%g\config\Folder%%g.cfg" "Folders\Folder%%%g\config\Backup\"
        rename "Folders\Folder%%g\config\Backup\Folder%%g.cfg" "Folder %date%.cfg"  
        timeout>nul 1
)

:end
cls
echo.
echo ========
echo = Done =
echo ========
echo.
    pause>nul
```

I was trying to make a file with modification date as name but i had some problems with time (22-03-2012 12:22).

This 12 ==>:<== 22 is trouble me. I don't know how to get rid of this. So instead you have current date as a file name.

Sorry for my English.

[Here is file with that batch and folders, so you can see how it works](http://speedy.sh/CGFHg/Help.rar)